# Unable to pass configuration to ngModel

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Directive

```
return {
     restrict: 'E',
     replace: true,
     transclude: true,
     require: ['^?angular-redactor', '^?ngModel'],
     scope: {
       options: '='
     },
      template: `<div ng-if="options.type=='redactor'">
             <textarea 
               id="{{options.id}}"
               ng-model="ngModel"
               ng-disabled="!hasPermission('editPageTitle')"
               height="{{options.height}}"
               style="{{options.style}}"
               redactor="{{options.config}}"> 
            </textarea>
          </div>`
        }
```

HTML

```
<txt ng-model="title"
    options="{
        type: 'redactor',
        id: 'title-input',
        height: '26px',
        style: 'resize:none; max-height: 32px' ,
        config: {
            minHeight: 37
        }
    }">
</txt>
```

I get the result ng-model="ngModel" instead of ng-model="title". I tried changing in my template ng-model="ngModel" to ng-model="{{ngModel}}". But it didn't work. Not sure as to why.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the scope of the directive to

```
scope: {
   options: '=',
   bindModel:'=ngModel'
},
```

and the template should be

```
    template: `<div ng-if="options.type=='redactor'">
         <textarea 
           id="{{options.id}}"
           ng-model="bindModel"
           ng-disabled="!hasPermission('editPageTitle')"
           height="{{options.height}}"
           style="{{options.style}}"
           redactor="{{options.config}}"> 
        </textarea>
      </div>`
    }
```

Comment: Didn't work sadly. The output was just `ng-model="bindModel"` instead of the desired `ng-model="title"`